# Changing background of NSButton with rounded buttons

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, nsbutton

I am trying to do some basic styling for an NSButton and I am changing the background colour. However it seems that the background colour is covering over my rounded corners.

How can I change the button background Colour for a rounded button?

Before adding Background
[image]

After  adding background: 
[image]

Code:

```
 testButton.title = "Start Test"
 testButton.state = .off
 testButton.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "stopwatch_Start")
 testButton.isBordered = false
 testButton.wantsLayer = true
 testButton.layer?.backgroundColor = NSColor.gray.cgColor
 testButton.isEnabled = true
```

Edit: 
I found that I was able to make the rectangle Clip round again if I added the follow:

```
testButton.layer?.masksToBounds = false
testButton.layer?.cornerRadius = 20
```

however it seems to be strange that I need to redo the corner radiues just when I change the button background

Answer (score 1):

You've set the button layer—which is a rectangle—to have a background color. That background fills the *entire* layer, which is a rectangle. So it's entirely expected that it fill it like so.

So yes, what you want is to set the `cornerRadius` in order to have rounded corners, but no, you do not needs to turn off `masksToBounds`. Doing so will let content *outside* the bounds of your button be visible. That's almost certainly not what you want.

Note that in general you can modify the layer of a button, but you may end up hitting some limitations. Unlike UIKit, AppKit was designed decades before Core Animation layers existed, so it's still primarily based around NSCell implementations, and layer-backed variants of controls will have different (undocumented) degrees of flexibility with regards to modification of the layer.

If you want complete control, it may be advisable to make an NSButton subclass which has is layer-hosting, not layer-backed, where you have complete control over the appearance of the button.